# Convert mysql query with doctrine query builder

Tags: php, sql, doctrine

My query looks like

```sql
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as cnt, ROUND(SUM(cost),2) as cost
FROM 
    (SELECT ROUND(SUM(cost),2) as cost FROM accounts LEFT JOIN earnings ON earnings.id = accounts.id WHERE earnings.date >= ? GROUP BY earnings.id) src;
```

How to write it using $querybuilder from Doctrine?

I have to mention that earnings are divided day by day, so that's why we have to do select from select.

I have tried:

```php
        $qb = $this->em->getConnection()->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->select('COUNT(*) as cnt, ROUND(SUM(cost),2) as cost');
        $qb->from(
            $qb->select('SELECT ROUND(SUM(cost),2) as cost')
                ->from('accounts')
                ->leftJoin('accounts', 'earnings', 'earnings', 'earnings.id = accounts.id')
                ->where('earnings.date >= :date')->setParameter(':date', $dto->getFromSqlFormat())
                ->groupBy('earnings.id')
        );
```

But it is not working and I am getting error:

```
Warning: Illegal offset type
```

Comment: What is the full error (with exact file and line number)?

Comment: `$qb->execute()->fetchAll());` This line is providing the error `Warning: Illegal offset type`

Comment: Try passing the subquery as a string instead of an object (call `->getQuery()` on it).

Comment: but it will pass query without parameters.

Comment: Move `->setParameter` to the outer query. Once the subquery is part of it, it will contain the same placeholder.

Comment: It won't work because the inner query is dynamically build based on input user. So we have to dynamically add ->andWhere

Comment: I don't see why that would be a problem. Just prepare the parameters in an array beforehand instead of including them one by one directly. Query builder can take an array through `setParameters` (note the plural).

Comment: It would look awful, how to repair the query from the question?

Comment: Look awful? Why? Where are these dynamic conditions coming from and in what form? What does it actually look like now (since the example in your question doesn't deal with the dynamic part at all)? Focus on making it work, then refactor if you're not satisfied with how it looks.